# Validation error: POST nested objects with DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models, one is `Voucher` and another one is `Journal`. I created a form with django formset to create a voucher for a set of journals. Each voucher must contain at least two transactions of journal.

Here are my `models`:

```
class Voucher(models.Model):
transactions_date   = models.DateField(default=now)
voucher_type        = models.CharField(max_length=2)
voucher             = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
narration           = models.CharField(max_length=100)
debit               = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
credit              = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.voucher)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Voucher'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Vouchers'
    default_related_name = 'voucher'


class Journal(models.Model):
account             = models.ForeignKey('Account', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
voucher             = models.ForeignKey('Voucher', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
debit               = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
credit              = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.voucher

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Journal'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Journals'
    default_related_name = 'journal'
```

Here are my `serializers.py`:

```
class JournalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
created_by = serializers.CharField(source="created_by.username", read_only=True)
updated_by = serializers.CharField(source="updated_by.username", read_only=True)
created_at = serializers.DateTimeField(format=settings.DATETIME_FORMAT, required=False)
updated_at = serializers.DateTimeField(format=settings.DATETIME_FORMAT, required=False)

class Meta:
    model = Journal
    fields =  '__all__'
 
class VoucherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    voucher_id = JournalSerializer(many=True)
    transactions_date = serializers.DateField(format=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMAT, required=True)
    created_by = serializers.CharField(source="created_by.username", read_only=True)
    updated_by = serializers.CharField(source="updated_by.username", read_only=True)
    created_at = serializers.DateTimeField(format=settings.DATETIME_FORMAT, required=False)
    updated_at = serializers.DateTimeField(format=settings.DATETIME_FORMAT, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Voucher
        fields =  '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        voucher_number = validated_data.pop('voucher_id ')
        voucher_instance = Voucher.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for journal in voucher_number:
            Journal.objects.create(voucher=voucher_instance, **journal)
        return voucher_instance
```

This `view` that I'm calling through Ajax:

```
class VoucherViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Voucher.objects.all()
serializer_class = VoucherSerializer
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = dict()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    
    if not serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        data['form_is_valid'] = False
        data['message'] = serializer.errors #"Form validation error!"
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        self.perform_create(serializer)    
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        data['form_is_valid'] = True
        data['message'] = "Successful saved."
    return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user, updated_by=self.request.user)
```

**Request:**

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

I've read so many posts here about nested objects but I'm still stuck with it "This field is required.".

Comment: Could you please post "serializer.errors" that you are getting while validating?

Comment: It says voucher: [ "This field is required." ]